# custom Tkinter button won't grid properly inside Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a custom Tkinter Button widget which inherits from the standard Button, purely for aesthetic purposes so that I can repeat the same style throughout all my program without have to configure it manually every time. The code for my custom Button is here:

```
import tkinter as tk

class gameButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(gameButton,self).__init__()

        self.root=args[0]

        self.configure(text=kwargs["text"])

        self.configure(fg=kwargs["fg"],
                       activeforeground=kwargs["fg"])

        try:
            self.configure(command=kwargs["command"])
        except KeyError:
            pass

        self.configure(relief="flat",cursor="hand2")
        self.bind("<Enter>",self.hover)
        self.bind("<Leave>",self.leave)

        self.old=kwargs["bg"]
        self.dark=self.darken(self.old)

        self.configure(bg=self.old,activebackground=self.dark,
                       bd=1,relief="solid")

    def getRGB(self,h):
        it=tuple(int(h[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2 ,4))
        return it

    def getHex(self,h):
        it='#%02x%02x%02x' % h
        return it

    def darken(self,h):
        currentHex=self.old.replace("#","")
        currentRGB=self.getRGB(currentHex)

        currentR=currentRGB[0]
        currentG=currentRGB[1]
        currentB=currentRGB[2]
        if currentR>30:
            newR=round(currentR-30)
        else:
            newR=0
        if currentG>30:
            newG=round(currentG-30)
        else:
            newG=0
        if currentB>30:
            newB=round(currentB-30)
        else:
            newB=0

        newRGB=(newR,newG,newB)

        newHex=self.getHex(newRGB)
        return newHex

    def hover(self,event):
        self.configure(bg=self.dark)

    def leave(self,event):
        self.configure(bg=self.old)
```

The section of the code where I'm trying to grid them in a Frame is here (I imported gameButton as GB):

```
game=Frame(notebook,bg=bg)
notebook.add(game,text="Game")

mapb=GB(game,text="Map",compound="left",bg=bg,fg=fg)
travelb=GB(game,text="Travel",compound="left",bg=bg,fg=fg)
bagb=GB(game,text="Bag",compound="left",bg=bg,fg=fg)

pokedexb=GB(game,text="Pokédex",compound="left",bg=bg,fg=fg)
partyb=GB(game,text="Party",compound="left",bg=bg,fg=fg)
saveb=GB(game,text="Save",compound="left",bg=bg,fg=fg)

mapb.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky="nesw")
travelb.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=5,sticky="nesw")
bagb.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=5,pady=5,sticky="nesw")

pokedexb.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky="nesw")
partyb.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5,pady=5,sticky="nesw")
saveb.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5,pady=5,sticky="nesw")
```

The result is this:

[image]

The button grids fine in a normal root window, but it refuses to behave properly inside a Frame inside a root.

Comment: you have to send `args` and `kwargs` to `super` so it will use it - `super(gameButton,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. Currently you create Button without parrent so it use `root` as parent and then it put it in different place that you expect.

Comment: widgets use `self.master`, not `self.root` to keep parent.

Comment: This solved it!! Thank you

Comment: @furas Please provide this as answer.

Comment: @furas: the name is irrelevant. Whether it's `self.master` or `self.root` is a matter of choice, not a tkinter requirement. Though, you are correct that `self.master` is arguably a better choice in this particular case.